# Rocket League won't save

Tags: debian, games, steam

I have the following System: Debian/GNU 8 Jessie.

I Have installed Steam through apt-get.

Now when I start Rocket League, it always goes back to some config I made like a year ago (also on linux).

If I change something in the Settings or on my car, it will only persist until I close the game. When I start the game again, all the settings and my car are set back to the one config I once made.

It does not matter if I enable the Steam-Cloud-Sync or not.

I even completely purged the Steam app and the corresponding directories and reinstalled a completely new Steam and RocketLeague, only to find out that the configuration gone back to the one I made long time ago.

The Steam support was so nice and told me they only support SteamOS, and not Debian.

Someone knows what I can do against that? (It is really annoying having to remap the controls every time I start the game xD)

Thanks, Jukisu.

EDIT: added console outputs:

```
jukisu@jp:~/.steam$ ls -lah
insgesamt 117M
drwxr-xr-x  19 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  9 20:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 109 jukisu jukisu  12K Okt 12 12:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:53 bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jukisu jukisu   31 Okt  9 20:12 bin32 -> /home/jukisu/.steam/ubuntu12_32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jukisu jukisu   31 Okt  9 20:12 bin64 -> /home/jukisu/.steam/ubuntu12_64
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu  12K Feb 11  2014 bin_steamdeps.py
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu 5,4K Nov 24  2016 bin_steam.sh
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 14:00 config
drwxr-xr-x   4 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 controller_base
-rw-r--r--   1 jukisu jukisu 117M Okt  9 22:33 error.log
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu  16K Okt  5 10:54 friends
drwxr-xr-x   3 jukisu jukisu  52K Okt  5 10:54 graphics
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 html5app
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 linux32
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 linux64
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 package
drwxr-xr-x   4 jukisu jukisu  20K Okt  5 10:54 public
-rw-r--r--   1 jukisu jukisu  578 Okt  9 20:12 registry.vdf
drwxr-xr-x   6 jukisu jukisu  16K Okt  5 10:54 resource
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jukisu jukisu   19 Okt  9 20:12 root -> /home/jukisu/.steam
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jukisu jukisu   27 Okt  9 20:12 sdk32 -> /home/jukisu/.steam/linux32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jukisu jukisu   27 Okt  9 20:12 sdk64 -> /home/jukisu/.steam/linux64
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 servers
drwxr-xr-x   2 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 skins
drwxr-xr-x  11 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  9 20:12 steam
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu  857 Okt  8  2013 steamdeps.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu 8,7K Feb  7  2013 steam_install_agreement.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu  869 Mär 24  2013 steam_msg.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 jukisu jukisu    6 Okt  9 20:12 steam.pid
prw-------   1 jukisu jukisu    0 Okt  5 10:49 steam.pipe
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu  29K Aug  3 02:19 steam.sh
drwxr-xr-x   3 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:53 tenfoot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu  405 Dez 24  2013 ThirdPartyLegalNotices.css
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu  25K Dez 17  2013 ThirdPartyLegalNotices.doc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jukisu jukisu 198K Jul 25 02:08 ThirdPartyLegalNotices.html
drwxr-xr-x   5 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:59 ubuntu12_32
drwxr-xr-x   4 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt  5 10:54 ubuntu12_64
```

and

```
jukisu@jp:~/.local/share/Rocket League$ ls -lah
insgesamt 16K
drwxr--r--  4 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Dez 12  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 53 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Okt 11 01:55 ..
drwxr--r--  3 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Dez 12  2016 Binaries
drwxr--r--  8 jukisu jukisu 4,0K Dez 13  2016 TAGame
```

It seems like everything has at least r/w permissions...

Comment: This does not seems a Unix doubt. I am in doubt this is borderline off-topic, but wont tag it as such. imo steam support is not being professional. A paying customer is a paying customer, and they should file a support ticket.

Comment: Well, if it isn't a Unix Problem, in which Forum should I ask? ;)
And yea, their only reply was like We don't care xD

Comment: You should find out where the program saves the configuration (then troubleshoot: check file permissions, observe if changes get applied, etc.). Do you have steam cloud enabled, it might also replace the configuration with one saved on valve's servers. If you launch the game from terminal, you might get additional output.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission problem. Not 100% sure where steam saves the games/configurations, but have look inside ~/.local/share/Steam.

You could also try starting steam as root user. Perhaps by doing "sudo steam" in terminal. Not able to be more specific atm since I do not have a testrig available.

Whenever you find the location of your game, please post a "ls -lah" of that folder and I might guide you if needed.

Edit: **PS!** Do not run your games using sudo or root user. This is just a step for troubleshooting. There are dangers running such applications as root. Doing a search on google it seems like steam have disabled the possibility for running as root/su.
To solve this temporarily for tests you could comment out that part:

```
# Don't allow running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]; then
    show_message --error $"Cannot run as root user"
    exit 1
fi
```

in the file /usr/bin/steam.

Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163566

Comment: I've posted the console outputs as an edit into my post.